# Power issue on Hp 15

Tags: battery, power, hp

This is what my nav bar looks, I don't know what that turbo like icon is, but once I disconnect my power cable, the laptop shots off. Does anyone know of a fix to this please?

Thank you.

Here is the output of `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`
[image: output of code run on terminal]

Here are the outputs from the updated command
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! How old is your notebook? Generally, if a machine loses power as soon as it’s disconnected from an outlet, it usually means that the battery is dead. If possible, could you [edit] your question to show the Terminal output of: `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`

Comment: According to the output of the `upower` command, there is no battery installed 

Comment: Wow, but then, sometimes it works normally but always giving same output when I run that `upower` command

Comment: Does `upower` return data for `battery_BAT1`? Usually a notebook battery is labelled as `BAT0`, but some manufacturers do “unique things” that can result in a different number being assigned 

Comment: How do I check what my battery is labeled as

Comment: Using `upower -d` will list all data related to the systems power devices, including AC. That will give you the name of the battery as well as its current status.

Comment: Seems like the battery name is `BAT1`. I'll update the post with more screenshot from the command you suggested and with the upower command with the correct battery name

Comment: Doing some digging, a lot of HP 15 notebooks require 19V of power to run. Your battery can put out a maximum of 16.544V, which is almost 2.5V less than the bare minimum. However, a lot of this can also depend on what hardware is inside your notebook. If you still have the paper manuals (or if you can get the PDF), check to see the minimum voltage required to run. If it's any number higher than 16.544, then your battery simply cannot discharge energy fast enough to keep your notebook running, which is why it powers off immediately.